# Coffee script multidimensional array creation

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, coffeescript

So I'm trying to get a multidimensional array to work in CoffeeScript. I have tried with standard Python list comprehension notation, that makes the inner bracket a string or something. so I can't do list[0][1] to get 1, I instead get list[0][0] = '1,1' and list[0][1] = ''

```
[[i, 1] for i in [1]]
```

Using a class as the storage container, to then grab x and y. Which gives 'undefined undefined', rather then '1 1' for the latter part.

```
class Position
    constructor:(@x,@y) ->

x = [new Position(i,1) for i in [1]]
for i in x
    alert i.x + ' ' + i.y#'undefined undefined'

i = new Position(1,1)
alert i.x + ' ' + i.y#'1 1'
```

Being able to use a list of points is extremely needed and I cannot find a way to make a list of them. I would prefer to use a simple multidimensional array, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use parenthesis, `()`, instead of square brackets, `[]`.

From a REPL:

```
coffee> ([i, 1] for i in [1])
[ [ 1, 1 ] ]
coffee> [[i, 1] for i in [1]]
[ [ [ 1, 1 ] ] ]
```

you can see that using the square brackets, as you would in Python, puts the generating expression inside of an extra list.

This is because the parenthesis, `()` are actually only there in CoffeeScript for when you want to assign the expression to a variable, so:

```
coffee> a = ([i, 1] for i in [1])
[ [ 1, 1 ] ]
coffee> a[0][1]
1
coffee> b = [i, 1] for i in [1]
[ [ 1, 1 ] ]
coffee> b[0][1]
undefined
```

Also, see the [CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/arrays/list-comprehensions).