# Is there anything similar to Python's numpy.apply_along_axis in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, numpy

I need to translate a Python program into Javascript and I see numpy.apply_along_axis many times but do not know how to do that in Javascript. Please help!

Comment: The Javascript arrays are like Python lists.  There's no inherent notion of axis or multidimensions.  Are you using any packages to enhance the array functionality?  Something like `underscore.js`?

Comment: I just started using Javascript and I don't know about any packages. Does the one you mention have something similar?

Comment: `underscore` (and clones) makes it easier to iterate through the various Javascript 'collections'.  But it is not a `numpy` like package.  Some other things that might make transition easier: JSON, Coffeescript, nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

There various ideas of how to create 'multidimensional arrays' in Javascript in this SO question from a few years back

[JavaScript multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Basically all use nested arrays, the equivalent of Python nested lists.

You have to have some sort of multidimensional array to have a concept of 'axis'.  Inevitably some operations will be easier on the first level array than on the deepest level.  And there will be speed penalties.

And for a syntax that looks more like Python, consider Coffeescript

[Coffee script multidimensional array creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597404/coffee-script-multidimensional-array-creation)

Packages like `underscore.js` and `lodash` have array/collection iterators and functions that can make operation on arrays  easier.  There are, for example, `zip` and `flatten` functions.

https://lodash.com/docs

Comment: The main point of `numpy` isn't to make it easy to create lists of lists. It is to provide high-performance, memory-efficient and blas-compatible arrays in python. Lists of lists are thousands of times slower than `numpy` arrays in python. I guess something similar could be created using asm.js, and I'm a bit surprised it doesn't already exist.